# JVCL Docking-Docking_in_Code example - Tab Dock possible error

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, docking, jvcl

I am using delphi xe2 with update 4, under OS: Win7, and I want to build an application for my semestre exam that allows docking forms. Because I am a student I can`t afford to buy any docking components. So I began to learn how JVCL Docking works by taking a look at the examples provided by JVCL 3.45 authors(thank you for them). And Now I am stuck with a possible problem. 
I have opened the project from JvDocking called Docking_in_Code: all the options in the left aligned panel(Sibling DOck, Cojoined Dock) are working, but when i click Tab Dock this is the message that I get

> "ManualTabDock:Ttabhost not created. Your docking style may not support tabbed docking"

Has anyone else encounterd this? I tried to write the same code in the example in my own project but the same error appears.[image] why it appears i can`t tell:(

Comment: I would advise you to jump over jvdock stuff for the time being, they are very buggy and not worth the time spent.

Comment: Hey Dorin, OUCH. I wrote those. If they're buggy, be a mensch, and report bugs in the Jedi Bug Tracker. And we'll fix them. Because we're nice like that.

Comment: Cristian;  Grab the latest sources using Subversion please, not the 3.45 sources, and see if that fixes your problem. If not, I'll wander in there and look into it further, but I'm not patching 3.45, I'll patch the CVS-head version. (That's how we roll with XE2 support.)

Comment: This is now reported as Bug 5874. http://issuetracker.delphi-jedi.org/view.php?id=5874

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing since you have made it to the stage of looking at examples, you have installed both JCL (Java Component Library) and JVCL (Java Visual Component Library) into Delphi XE2.

I have just been learning how to work with the JVCL docking components recently as well. This example was one of the first I looked at and it worked fine for me. I suggest you reinstall JCL and the JVCL then double check that the library paths are present and correct in:

```
Tools > Options > Environment Options > Delphi Options > Library > LibraryPath
```

I have the following paths saved in my directory listing:

```
...\jcl\jcl\lib\d16\win32
...\jcl\jcl\source\include
...\jvcl\lib\D16\win32
...\jvcl\common
...\jvcl\Resources
...\jvcl\run
```

If you have confirmed this all and it is still not working, it may be an idea to install the packages manually. The package version that needs to be installed is D16 for both JCL and JVCL if you need to manually compile and install the packages (the installer should do this for you though). If you open up the 'D16 Packages' delphi project you should be able to manually install the components, for first the JCL, and then the JVCL.